# Как выполнить подзапрос используя PHQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, phalcon

Есть такой запрос:

```
  SELECT Messages.*
FROM (
SELECT MAX(id) AS 'maxid', IF (author = 'Gildars', recipient, author) AS 'user'
FROM Messages
WHERE author = 'Gildars' or recipient = 'Gildars'
GROUP BY user
) AS a
INNER JOIN Messages ON a.maxid = id
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Мне нужно этот запрос выполнить используя PHQL.
Вот как я пытался его выполнить:

```
$this->modelsManager->executeQuery("SELECT Aincrad\Models\Messages.*
FROM (
SELECT MAX(id) AS 'maxid', IF (author = 'Gildars', recipient, author) AS 'user'
FROM Aincrad\Models\Messages
WHERE author = 'Gildars' or recipient = 'Gildars'
GROUP BY user
) AS a
INNER JOIN Aincrad\Models\Messages ON a.maxid = id
ORDER BY id DESC
");
```

Но все глухо.
Вот ошибка.

```
Syntax error, unexpected token (, near to ' 
SELECT MAX(id) AS 'maxid', IF (author = 'Gildars', recipient, author) AS 'user'
 FROM Aincrad\Models\Messages WHERE author = 'Gildars' or recipient = 'Gildars' GROUP BY user ) AS a INNER JOIN Aincrad\Models\Messages ON a.maxid = id ORDER BY id DESC ',
when parsing: SELECT Aincrad\Models\Messages.* FROM ( SELECT MAX(id) AS 'maxid',
 IF (author = 'Gildars', recipient, author) AS 'user' FROM Aincrad\Models\Messages WHERE author = 'Gildars' or recipient = 'Gildars' GROUP BY user )
 AS a INNER JOIN Aincrad\Models\Messages ON a.maxid = id ORDER BY id DESC (314)
```

Comment: Вместо AS 'maxid' напишите AS maxid. Что получится?

Comment: Может он не понимает подзапросы в FROM. Перенесите подзапрос в where: `select * from messages where id in(select max(id) from ... group by IF(author=....))`

Comment: Не помогло, все также  ошибка.

Comment: Возможно Phalcon не поддерживает подзапросы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHQL не поддерживает подзапросы. 
Для того чтобы выполнить запрос необходимо использовать PDO.

Например:

```
$sql = "
SELECT Messages.*
FROM (
    SELECT MAX(id) AS 'maxid', IF (author = :author, recipient, author) AS 'user'
    FROM Messages
    WHERE author = :author or recipient = :recipient
    GROUP BY user
) AS a
INNER JOIN Messages ON a.maxid = id
ORDER BY id DESC";
                    $messages =  $this->db->query($sql,(array(
                        "author" => $auth['login'],
                        "recipient" => $auth['login']
                    )));
                    $messages->setFetchMode(\Phalcon\Db::FETCH_OBJ);
                    $messages = $messages->fetchAll();
```